# dns_get_record problems

Tags: php

I am setting up a dns lookup form using dns_get_record.

I set it up to check the A Record and MX Records and NS records of the domain that is input. However, I would like it to also to get the full TTL of a record?

also is it possible to query direct to the named service on port 53 (UDP)?

Comment: The TTL is part of the SOA, so just query for `DNS_SOA`

Comment: but some records has different ttl then the soa e.g. google

   soa = [ttl] => 300

and other record  [6] => Array ( [host] => google.com [type] => NS [target] => ns3.google.com [class] => IN [ttl] => 63489

Comment: google's 300 ttl is the 'minimum-ttl'. maximum ttl is 15339. That's going to be different for everyone, depending on their needs and setup. And following up for your next comment: it makes sense to have a LONG ttl on a name server address, as that's supposed to be unchanging. google's main page could potentially jump around servers/data centers often, so a short ttl makes sense there. again - everyone's going to have different TTLs on their hostnames, even on subdomains, depending on the the particular needs of that hostname/domain.

Comment: but is there a way to query the named service directly ?